# For domains pointed to a subdirectory, how do I access sibling directories while still being able to develop on localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, virtualhost

The file structure for a website I have in development is as such:

delucion/

- www/ - this is where the main website files go
- lib/, src/, etc - these are on the same level as the www/ folder, and contain other files for use on the website

On localhost, having sibling directories is not an issue. Right now, I have two domains with my webhost, ipage. One is www.theworldwithin.org (the root), and the other is [www.delucion.com](http://www.delucion.com) . I pointed delucion.com to [www.theworldwithin.org/delucion/www/](http://www.theworldwithin.org/delucion/www/) . As you can see by testing it, both urls work, but the one at www.delucion.com cannot import, via html or javascript, the files served at ../lib/ . I suppose this makes sense, because the domain is being treated as the root, and I know I could just rewrite all my links to serve those resources from www.theworldwithin.org/delucion/lib/, but then I wouldn't be able to keep consistency between my localhost and online files. Is there a clean way to do this? A way to serve resources from a sibling folder, even though it's not one that can be navigated to under the current domain, but is instead just in the underlying file system?

Also, this is NOT a problem on the server-side, as header.php is in /lib, but is still included in the file. All references within html and javascript, however, are broken.

Comment: i would define a global root variable and use that, or the php constants: `__DIR__` \ `__FILE__`

Comment: Not really following.  Might help to see host file for the server and a image of your directory structure.  Can't tell if you need mod_rewrite, symlinks, or a redo of your setup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Dagon! I did my research and got things to work to my liking using a global root variable - I just have it defined differently on my localhost vs on the web server, and it allows me to keep everything else the same. Thank you again : ) .

Also, thanks ficuscr for reading and trying to help, sorry that I wasn't clear. All the same, the issue is now fixed.